# Django app's DB user failed authentication in AWS

Tags: django, database, postgresql

Here is Django setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'rulings',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

In AWS, when I run a server, an error message occurs.

```
File "/home/app_admin/venv_ruling/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: 
FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How can I run the server with the user name of postgres??
When I use another user name it will run without a problem, but I want to use "postgres" as a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "peer" authentication can even be configured on RDS, so you must be running your own PostgreSQL server on EC2?  Since you apparently want to use password authentication, change your pg_hba to specify "md5", rather than "peer".

Also, it is a bad practise to run an app as "postgres".  That user is supposed to be reserved for maintenance operations.